# Call an office 365 authenticated web api from a sharepoint page javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication, sharepoint, office365

I have a scenario that I think should be fairly simple, yet I'm not finding a solution and wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

**The setup:**

1) SharePoint online website (user must be authenticated to see page)

2) .NET MVC Web API service endpoint (user must be authenticated to get data from the service)

Both of these authenticate using the same Azure Active Directory.  The Web API has been registered in Azure AD.

**The problem:**

I would like to put some javascript on a SharePoint Online page (not a Sharepoint Add-in, not an AngularJS SPA) that will make an AJAX call to the Web API using the logged in user's credentials without any kind of user prompt (since this is an ajax call, the user won't see the prompt anyway).

I've tried looking into the ADAL libraries, but all the JavaScript ones I can find require the use of Angular and require the user to authenticate a second time.  I've found some documentation using OAuth 2.0, but (from what I can tell) require you to get the client to authorize the Sharepoint Online page to act on their behalf - which the user will not be able to consent to because it's an AJAX call and the consent page is not displayed in the browser (and it's still doing this despite having the app already approved by an administrator in Azure AD).

It seems to me the user shouldn't have to leave the SharePoint page and shouldn't have to enter their credentials a second time.  I believe there should be some way that the log-in to SharePoint Online should also be able to be used as the log-in for our in-house app.

If someone could just point me in the correct direction, I would be very much appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if we call the resource which protected by Azure AD, we need to authorize the app via OAuth 2.0.

Were you able to put a hidden iframe in the SharePoint online page? If it is possible, then we can use the Azure AD implicit flow get the token through iframe, and we can call the REST which protected by Azure AD via the token return by iframe. To enable the implicit flow, we need to download the application manifest from Azure portal and switch ‘oauth2AllowImplicitFlow’ to **true**.

And if you were only developing a single tenant which doesn’t require users to consent the app. Here is the HTML code request the token from a Iframe for your reference:

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" id="oauthHideIframe" src="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={Client_Id}&redirect_uri={redirect_Url}&resource={your web api app url register on the protal}"> </iframe>
```

And to pass the token from iframe to the parent window, we can use the **window.postmessage** which allow the corss-orignal communication.